# jQuery UI .tooltip() Not Detecting New DOM Elements in Gravity Forms

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dom, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a form that is generated via Gravity Forms for WordPress:
- http://www.mattpealing-server.co.uk/~devappli/register/

And have set the little '+ / -' icons to display tooltips to give instructions to the user with this simple bit of code:

```
$('.add_list_item, .delete_list_item').tooltip();
```

You can see how it looks here:

[image]

However, when I add a new row using the '+' button, notice how any subsequent rows do not have a tooltip show up when you hover over the icons:

[image]

I see no errors in the FF error console. Can anyone see the problem? I hear that this particular plugin is supposed to detect new DOM elements?

Comment: Do you call `tooltip()` on the new rows or do you just call it on the original row? Even though you're using classes, it's matching on the class name and running the tooltip function against the matched DOM items of the moment. But it's not going to run it against things that get added to the DOM later.

Comment: Ah I see! I was under the impression jQuery UI would detect future DOM elements?

I'm not sure how I would set it to pick up DOM elements that are added later other than using classes in the selector?

Comment: You could simply rerun `$('.add_list_item, .delete_list_item').tooltip()` each time you add the new elements at the end of gformAddListItem().